# Why are my margins being applied in my containing div instead of being applied on it?

Tags: html, css

I have a 2 forms which are both nested in a containing div. I am trying to place both forms(and their containing divs) side by side via the use of floats.

While i am able to do so successfully, upon closer examination of the containing divs using chrome's developer tools, i noticed that while my forms are placed apart from each other, the margins specified the the css are being applied to the forms **inside** the containing divs and not **on** the containing div, though it was specified in the css for the containing div.

HTML(Extract)

```
<div id='UserRegistrationContainer'>

        <div id='UserRegistrationCover' class='RegistrationFormCover'>
            <input type='button' id='UserSignUp' value='Sign up today!' />
        </div>

        <form id='UserRegistration' class='RegistrationForm' method='POST' action='#'>

            //Form inputs/details here

        </form>

    </div>

<div id='ShopRegistrationContainer'>
        <div id='ShopRegistrationCover' class='RegistrationFormCover'>
            <input type='button' id='ShopSignUp' value='Sign up today!' />
        </div>

        <form id='ShopRegistration' class='RegistrationForm' method='POST' action='#'>

            //Form inputs/details here

        </form>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.RegistrationFormCover{
    position:absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #0000CC;
    z-index: 100; }

#UserRegistrationContainer{
    position: relative;
    float:left;
    width:40%; }

#UserRegistration{
    display:inline-block; }

#ShopRegistrationContainer{
     position: relative;
    float:left;
    width:40%;
    margin-left: 50px; }

#ShopRegistration{
    display:inline-block; }
```

Visual example

Why am i getting this

```
<UserRegistrationContainer><------ShopRegistration Container-------------->
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
                          |                |                              |
                          |                |                              |
                          |                |                              |
                          |      50px      |                              |
   UserRegistration       |  <--margin --> |     ShopRegistration         |
                          |                |                              |
                          |                |                              |
                          |                |                              |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

and not getting this?

```
<UserRegistrationContainer>                <--ShopRegistration Container-->
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
                          |                |                              |
                          |                |                              |
                          |                |                              |
                          |       50px     |                              |
   UserRegistration       |  <--margin --> |     ShopRegistration         |
                          |                |                              |
                          |                |                              |
                          |                |                              |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x6SfW/

Comment: can you provide fiddle please ?

Comment: @bboymaanu i've added the jsfiddle :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your first issue is that so many of your divs have their position property set as well as float property. All of those css styles have very specific uses and from what I can tell they are not entirely necessary for what you are trying to accomplish, two vertically aligned divs with each with two sections that take up ~80% of the page.

First lets look at the HTML.

```
<div id="userRegistration" class="registration">
    <div>
        <input type='button' value='Sign up today!' />
    </div>
    <form method='POST' action='#'>

        //Form inputs/details here

    </form>
</div>
<div id="shoppingRegistration"  class="registration">
    <div>
        <input type='button' value='Sign up today!' />
    </div>
    <form method='POST' action='#'>

        //Form inputs/details here

    </form>
</div>
```

Removed extra tags ids and classes which are unnecessary.
Next up is the CSS.

```
.registration div{ //replaces RegistrationFormCover

    width:      100%;
    height:     100%;
    background: #0000CC;
    z-index:    100;

}
.registration {

    width:    40%;
    float:    left;
    position: relative;

}
.registration form {

    display: inline-block;

}
#shoppingRegistration{

    margin-left: 50px;

}
```

As to your actual problem right now I just realized you probably just miss read the chrome developer tools. The orange color represents a margined area not an actual piece of the div.
Either way the code here works so good luck and I hope it helps you.